# Trouble Google Script in Sheets to Print from A1 to cell that contains text "stop print". sheet.setPrintArea not a function- anything similar?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've been working with both ChatGPT and Google Bard trying to learn how to do this.

It seems that sheet.setPrintArea is not a function nor does there seem to be one similar.

I did a search on developers.google with no results-  am I missing an option or is this just not possible?

I'm trying to create this script because the number of rows changes every time I use this sheet.

function printRange() {
// Declare variables
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxx");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Invoice");
var rng = sheet.getRange("A1");
var strStopPrint = "stop print";

// Find the cell that contains "stop print"
var stopPrintCell = sheet.createTextFinder(strStopPrint).findNext();

// Get the range from A1 to the cell containing "stop print"
var printRange = sheet.getRange(rng.getRow(), rng.getColumn(), stopPrintCell.getRow() - rng.getRow() + 1, stopPrintCell.getColumn());

// Set the range as the print area
sheet.setPrintArea(printRange.getA1Notation());

// Print the sheet
sheet.print();
}

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). You can finish the code faster by studying the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) instead of debugging generative AI hallucinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Sheet.setPrintArea()` or `Sheet.print()` method. You need to generate a PDF file and upload or email it to some endpoint where it can be printed.

One good way to get started is to use Google's [createPDF()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/generate-pdfs) sample code. The range to include in the PDF is specified with this line:

```
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).